# Returning only the last value

Tags: codeigniter, foreach

Returning only the last value

The code works only if the last item of for each loop, help me

this is my view code

```
<?php if($value->lnkCod == $link_id){echo'exemple';}?>

<div class=""></div>
<div class=""></div>
<div class=""></div>
<div class="exemple"></div>
```

Model

```
public function AddClass($user_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('lnkCod');
        $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);

        $query = $this->db->get('site_votos');

        return $query->result_array();


    }
```

Controller

```
$user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
$id_post_addclass = $this->user->AddClass($user_id);

        foreach ($id_post_addclass as $valor) {

            $lnkCod = $valor['lnkCod'];
        }

        $this->data['link_id'] = $lnkCod;

$this->load->view('site/home/index', $this->data);
```

Comment: You are overwriting your variable `$lnkCod` in each loop iteration – so of course you’ll only get the last value (if that’s what you’re actually asking, hard to tell).

Comment: +1 @CBroe, loop mistake.

Comment: @CBroe how not to replace?

Comment: Well for example by placing the data into an array instead … it really depends on what you actually want to achieve here. (Although `$id_post_addclass` seems to be an array or array-like structure already, so maybe just returning that would be enough already … you should know best, it’s your code and your data.)

Answer (score 0):

You are not placing the data in array.I wonder what you want to achieve but if you want to put all your data in $lnkCod then you should first declare it as array like this

```
$lnkCod = array();
```

then in your foreach loop use like this

```
 foreach ($id_post_addclass as $valor) {

            $lnkCod[] = $valor['lnkCod'];
        }

data['link_id'] = $lnkCod;
$this->load->view('your_view',$data);
```

Feel free to let me know if you have any question.

--Update--

In your view you have can access like this

```
foreach($link_id as $id)
{
echo $id;
}
```

Comment: foreach ($id_post_addclass as $valor) {

                    $lnkCod[] = $valor['lnkCod'];
                }

                $this->data['link_id'] = $lnkCod;

$this->load->view('site/home/index', $this->data);

view
<?php echo $link_id; ?>

return error
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: home/index.php
Line Number: 9
Array

Comment: you need specify index if you want to echo the value without for loop else you need to put it in foreach and echo the val which is required.

For example :
You need to do this in your view
foreach($link_id as $id)
{
echo $id; //this will print all your array data.
}

Comment: It worked, but it just keeps taking the last.

foreach($link_id as $id) {
    echo $id;
} 
lnkCod is the id of the post
<?php if($value->lnkCod == $id){echo'exemple';}?>

Comment: Don't you getting all your id printed after executing foreach ?

Also if you want to compare it with $value->lnkCod and echo then you will receive single result as you are doing it that way.

If you can tell me what you want to achieve i can better help you.

Comment: Yes, it's getting all ids, but the comparison only captures one id.
I want to add a class in all posts with id equal to foreach.

Comment: ok but if you made single comparison check you will get the matched output right.

As you say you want to add class in all posts do you want to add different classes to each post or same class.

Also again i am asking you if you could tell me the scenario you are trying to implement i can help you better.

Comment: Try the updated pastebin code and let me if you need further help.
http://pastebin.com/CJDcMWu6

Comment: It did not work, returned multiple values ​​from sql, try another way with cookies maybe. 
Many thanks for the help,;)

Comment: definitely it will return multiple values if you fire query such way.if you want specific value you need to be clear to get exact help.

Comment: It's a system I liked, where the click action saves in a database, and the home page checks the data liked, and adds the class.

Comment: Ok.so i got you correct this time you want to add 'liked' and disable like feature if its already liked..am i right ?

If so i guess it should be like displaying your post with foreach and check if lnkcode array has value set as liked for specific post as 
`in_array($value->lnkCod, $link_id)? 'true' : 'false'`

try this if